# ipv4 HEADER CHECKSUM

Tags: tcp

I'm a beginner of TCP/IP suite.

One field of ip header named HEADER CHECKSUM is formed by treating the header as a sequence of 16 bit integers,adding them together using one's complement arithmetic,and then taking the one's complement of the result.

But the ip header also includes TTL field,which may change in the transmission. 
Why would it not lead inconsistence between the sender and receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The checksum is recomputed at every hop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)

> As the TTL field is decremented on each hop, a new checksum must be
>   computed each time. The method used to compute the checksum is defined
>   by RFC 1071

Comment: Incidentally, this continual recomputing of the checksum is why many higher-end TCP networking devices have "tcp offload engines", to accelerate this checksumming without bogging down the actual cpu of the host device.